# After trying every "bugfix" react-router redux push still not rerendering,

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

we still have the issue that after push from 'react-router-redux' the url changes but the dom is not rerendering. Even after reading and trying:

- https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4924
- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Reboot } from 'material-ui';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Shell from '../Shell';
import Home from '../Home';
import Verify from '../Verified';
import Event from '../Event/EventWrapper';
import RoomWrapper from '../Room/RoomWrapper';
import Room from '../Room/RoomComponent';

const App = () => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Reboot/>
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Shell/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path="/room" component={RoomWrapper}/>
                    <Route path="/room/:id" component={Room}/>
                    <Route exact path="/event" component={Event}/>
                    <Route exact path="/verify" component={Verify}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
);

export default withRouter(App);
```

Component

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    handleCreate: (roomName, roomHash) => {
        dispatch(valueRoomCreateWithRouteChange(roomName, roomHash));
    },
});

@withRouter
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
@withStyles(styles)
class RoomCreate extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: String,
    };

    handleChange = event => this.setState({ name: event.target.value });

    render() {
        const { name } = this.state;
        const {
            classes, handleCreate,
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className={classes.relative}>
                    <TextField
                        className={classes.textField}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        autoFocus
                        margin="dense"
                        id="name"
                        label="Room name"
                        type="text"
                        fullWidth
                        required/>
                    <Button raised color="secondary"
                        onClick={() => {
                            handleCreate(name, randomString({ length: 5, letters: 'uppercase' }));
                        }}
                        className={classes.primary}>
                        Create
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Action

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

export const ROOM_CREATE = 'ROOM_CREATE';

export const valueRoomCreate = (roomName, roomHash) => ({
    type: ROOM_CREATE,
    roomName,
    roomHash,
    created: true,
});

// TODO: Implement async method wi`enter code here`th router push

export const valueRoomCreateWithRouteChange = (roomName, roomHash) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(valueRoomCreate(roomName, roomHash));
    dispatch(push(`/room/${roomHash}`));
};
```

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted we can see that you are using the BrowserRouter. This uses the HTML5 history API which syncs your UI to your browsers url.

For use with Redux, you would instead use Router and pass your own history object. That same history object would also be supplied to your router middleware when creating the redux store. See [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) for example.

Assuming, you have set up your provider correctly, using ConnectedRouter instead from the react-router-redux library automatically uses the store passed to provider through context.

Also from [this important note](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#important-note) we know that simply wrapping your component in this HOC will not cause a rerender on route transitions unless its parent component rerenders. So perhaps that is also a problem.

If none of the above points help you to resolve the issue, provide more of your code and I will be happy to take another look.